# How to handle large collections in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Entry entity and a Comment entity. The Entry entity has a OneToMany association to the Comment entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entries")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public boolean containsComment(int commentId) {
        return comments.contains(commentId);
    }

    public Comment getComment(int commentId) {
        return comments.get(commentId);
    }

    public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
       comments.remove(comment);
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="comments")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Entry entry;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entry getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(Entry entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }
}
```

Lets assume I have a Single Page App that send the following request to the backend:

```
/deleteComment?entryId=5&commentId=7
```

My approach would be in the controller to fetch the Entry by the entryId param. 
Than I would like to call on the Entry-entity the containsComment)()-method where I would pass the commentId request parameter. So I would get true if the collections contains a comment with the given id, or false. If true I would call the getComment()-method to get the Comment entity.
Finally I would simply call the removeComment()-method with the Comment entity as parameter.

In PHP Doctrine I think this approach worked. Is this a correct way in hibernate too?

In the example code if I call the containsComment() method I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public int com.mypackage.Comment.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.mypackage.Comment#id] : 7
```

Note that I work with EXTRA-LAZY because the comments can quickly get a large collection.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that with a query, e.g. if `Comment` has a reference back to `Entry` use something like `select c from Comment c where c.id = :commentId and c.entry.id = :entryId` - if you get that comment then it exists and you can use it right away.

Deleting the comment is easy, just do it. Since `Comment` is the owner of the relation deleting it will effectively remove it from the entry as well.

One word of advice though: HQL/JPQL queries use the keyword `id` for id properties. In your case it's ok since `id` is annotated with `@Id`. However, if you have another `@Id` field the query will behave differently from what you expect since using `id` in a query will assume you mean the `@Id` field(s).

Finally a sidenote on `comments.contains(commentId)`: Java collections like lists normally will look for the element you pass as the parameter but since your collection is a `List<Comment>` and you pass an id (which is an `int`) it should not be found. I'm not sure whether the Hibernate collections employ some special translation logic but to a Java programmer that call looks like an error as you'd never expect that to return true (it's like "does the list of apples contain this orange?").